# how can i get aws launch config from AMI iD

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have made script who clean ami id based on from not running instances. 
but i want also delete feature this script to clean launch config form AMI ID(actually who are not exist).

```
good_images = set([instance.image_id for instance in ec2.instances.all()])

#LaunchConfig in use AMI
client = boto3.client('autoscaling', region_name=region)
response = client.describe_launch_configurations()
ls_list=[]
for LC in response['LaunchConfigurations']:
    (LC['ImageId'])
print ls_list

but its not working.
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but it is not clear what you are trying to do. Can you please try again to explain what you are trying to achieve? Also, you are not adding results to `ls_list` in your `for` loop.

Comment: @John I am trying to delete old launch config based on AMI.

Comment: Your code is getting a list of AMIs from all instances. It is then looping through Launch Configurations and retrieving the associated AMI (but not doing anything with it). Please Edit and rewrite your question to explain exactly what you are wanting to do, or what you want the code sample to do.

Comment: ok i will update this but its not printing any launch confing..based on AMI ID.. is there any configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
for LC in response['LaunchConfigurations']:
    (LC['ImageId'])
```

should be:

```
for LC in response['LaunchConfigurations']:
    (ls_list.append(LC['ImageId']))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
used_lc = []
all_lc = []
def used_launch_config():
    for asg in client.describe_auto_scaling_groups()['AutoScalingGroups']:
        launch_config_attached_with_asg = asg['LaunchConfigurationName']
        used_lc.append(launch_config_attached_with_asg)
used_launch_config()
print used_lc

def all_spot_lc():
    for launch_config in client.describe_launch_configurations(MaxRecords=100,)['LaunchConfigurations']:
        lc = launch_config['LaunchConfigurationName']
        if str(lc).startswith("string"):
           all_lc.append(lc)
all_spot_lc()
print all_lc
```

I just avoid to delete launch config from AMI.
Now i compared from used or unused it solved the problem.
I was doing wrong in Previous code.

> is there way to increase max records